# This API key is not authorized to use this service or API

Tags: python, api, request, geolocation, access-denied

I am trying to do my Geolocation python program. I have already had an API key. I also enable geocoding API, Map static API, direction API, Distance matrix API, geolocation API, places API, map javascript API.
[image: APIs description]

However, I received this message:

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

<GeocodeResponse>
<status>REQUEST_DENIED</status>
<error_message>This API key is not authorized to use this service or API.</error_message>
</GeocodeResponse>
```

the link I want to access: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?sensor=false&address=pentagon&key=MYKEY

What should I do to solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

Log into google developers console.

Make sure the project you want to access is selected.

In the navigation panel on the left select APIs and Services

There in the panel on the left select credentials.

Under API Keys click on the pencil (edit) icon.

Scroll down to API Restrictions and select do not restrict key and save.

If that does not work you need to check to make sure the project is linked to a billing account, you will need to provide a credit card for this part.